# Negating one time from another

Tags: php

Hey guys i'm trying to figure out how to subtract one time from another using php to get the amount of time left between the two times. So for example

time left = time1-time2

or

timeleft = 15:35-15:30

which would be equal to 5mins left.

Currently I am loading the two times like so.

time1 is coming from my database (which is the time we are waiting for, and in my case the time we are waiting for is the time for next update) and time2 is the current system time.

I tried using this code

```
$timeleft = $dbtime - $curtime;
```

$dbtime = time loaded from database.
$curtime = current system time.

But that just returns a 0.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtotime` to turn the date string to unix timestamp.

```
$timeleft = strtotime($dbtime) - strtotime($curtime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You negating one string from another - the result in 0 because `(int)(string) = 0`

Your must use like this

```
$dbtime = time();
// query
$timeleft = time() - $dbtime;
```

See also `strtotime()` function, if you date is parsed by it

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert both times into timestamp. One good function for that is the strtotime() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php that try to convert a string into timestamp.

Then do your maths as you know and then just use the date() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php function to fomrat your time into anything you like

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` to convert strings to unix timestamps:

```
$timedifference = strtotime($dbtime) - strtotime($curtime); // or also
$timedifference = strtotime($dbtime) - time();
```